# Issue using jQuery to do a google maps api call (JSON not being returned)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, jsonp

This is the code I was originally using and worked perfectly fine up until yesterday (which is when I noticed it but I am unsure when it actually stopped working for sure).  I know this was working at the beginning of last week so sometime between then and yesterday it broke.  I am running this code within a RAD called Alpha Anywhere but have tested it outside of this program (in just a HTML page) and it still didn't work.  Hoping someone knows if there is a bug or if there is something I can do to fix this issue. I ran this in firefox with firebug on and that is where I saw the error letting me know that the JSON wasn't retrieved.

```js
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

$jq.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false',function(results){

    // I have code in here to calculate miles driven per state 
    // (as in the above code origin and destination would be filled 
    // with variables but I went with this basic call because even this doesn't work).

});
```

---

This following code does not work (as of right now November 11, 2013 at 10:26 PM CDT) when running it in firefox or chrome.  With firebug on it shows I am not getting a response from google.  However this following code does respond when ran in safari 7.0.x on Mac OSX 10.9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getData() {
                var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Huntsville,AL&destination=Atalanta,GA&sensor=false';
                var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
                $jq.getJSON(url, function (results) {
                    alert(results.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
                });
            }
        </script>
        <title>jQuery Debug of Google API</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="getData();">click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the url is commenting out the rest of the code.  I'd bet you need to put quotes around it.

Comment: I apologize for that mistyping, my code has the url properly quoted. Thank you for pointing this out on here so I could get that fixed in my question.  Anyone else having this same issue using jQuery and the google maps api?

Comment: Solved It!  It was a combination of not requesting JSONP and not being served it once it was requested.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here:

First, from [**jsonp explained**](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/):

> As you may be aware **you cannot directly load data files from another domain**. This is a security issue that has been around for a long time and is commonly solved by sharing data through an API, REST or such. **However there are ways around this** ... [for example] JSONP

To do this in jQuery:

- Using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), add `dataType: 'jsonp'`, which *appends callback=? to the URL*
- Using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) (*[shorthand for `.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/)*), add  [`callback=?`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) at the end of the requested URL.

That indicates that we want to use [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Remove it and a vanilla JSON request will be used; which will fail due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

---

Another issue is that some external APIs (like *Google Maps [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)*), don't automatically serve JSONP.  If the server doesn't know what to do with the callback parameter then the response from the API will still be JSON, not JSONP.  In order to ensure the returned content is formatted correctly, you can go through a proxy server like the [jsonp.guffa.com](http://jsonp.guffa.com/)

To use it, change the request to `http://jsonp.guffa.com/Proxy.ashx?url=YourEncodedURI`
Where you have replaced *YourEncodedURI* with the [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) requested url string.

---

#### Putting it all together:

```js
var mapsUrl    = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json' + 
                 '?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false';
var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(mapsUrl);
var proxyUrl   = 'http://jsonp.guffa.com/Proxy.ashx?url=' + encodedUrl;

$.ajax({
    url: proxyUrl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

## [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/bFc4y/)

---

Further Reading:

- [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584/1366033)

Comment: For some reason I was able to get this working by deleting the semi-colon at the very end of the getJSON call.  However, for some reason it is now again not responding. I am looking into this now but am having a hard time understand why it works sometimes and doesn't others.  I have edited my original post with an attached document that does the jQuery call (just a standard HTML page) and if you run it in firefox with firebug on you will see there is no response from google.  However this page run in safari 7.0.x (on Mac OSX 10.9) does respond.